# how run asynctask inside asynctask in the same time?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have an web-based application that must retrive text in external database and image in server after one text retrived ,using following code for retrive text:

```
class BackgroundTaskOne extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{

    String json_url;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        json_url="http://..some url../somefile.php";

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

        String error="";
        try {
            URL url=new URL(json_url);

            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream=httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();

            while((JSON_STRINO=bufferReader.readLine())!=null){

                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRINO+"\n");
                //add new textView  
            }

            bufferReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
            json_string=stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
           // return "one row of data inserted..";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            error=e.getMessage()+" first";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            error=e.getMessage()+" sec";
        }
        return error;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        json_string=result;
        l=parse();


           int i=0;

           for(final String a[]:l){

               TextView t=new TextView(MainActivity.this);

               final String path=a[2]+".jpg";
                t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
               t.setText(a[0]+" : "+a[1]+" i="+i);             
                t.setId(i);
                Reklam.addView(t);

                new LoadImage().execute(path);

            i++;
    }}}
```

i want to load image while loading first text and second image after second text in sequence but it loads all text then load all images , these folowing code for loading image:

```
 private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
        pDialog.show();

    }
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
         try {
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

         if(image != null){
         ImageView img=new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
         img.setImageBitmap(image);
         img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Reklam.addView(img);
         pDialog.dismiss();

         }else{

         pDialog.dismiss();
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to run multiple thread parallely :

```
 if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
        new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }
```